# My djcelery tasks run locally but not remotely?

Tags: python, django, heroku, task, cron

I have automated tasks working locally but not reomotely in my django app. I was watching a tutorial and the guy said to stop my worker. but before I did that I put my app in maintenance mode, that didn't work. then I ran

```
heroku ps:restart
```

that didn't work, then I ran

```
heroku ps:stop worker
```

which outputed

```
 Warning: The dynos in your dyno formation will be automatically restarted.
```

then I ran

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

and still nothing. I remind those who are reading this that it worked locally. What am I missing?

my procfile

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery worker -A blog -l info.
```

While researching I'm seeing mentions of adding beat to the procfile. 2 mentions in fact but this was not discussed in the tutorial I watched. only time celery beat was mentioned is when I added this to the settings.py file

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

and just in case it makes a difference I'm using the djcelery gui to set periodic tasks not configuring the sceduler in the settings.py like I see in a majority of the examples.

If I run the task in my view and call it, it works. But it wont run if I set it up using djcelery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the docs and realized I had to add to my worker procfile

```
-B
```

so it now looks like this

```
celery -A proj worker -B -l info
```

after I made the change I did this

```
heroku ps:scale worker=0
```

then

```
git add .
git commit -am 'added -B'
git push heroku master
```

then I

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

then so I could see the output from heroku

```
heroku logs -t -p worker
```

and created a schedule in my admin and it worked. I saw the output in the console. Hope this helps. NOTE it says it's not recomended for production not sure why but if you know or find out let me know

Answer (score 0):

As you've read in the docs, using the **-B** option is not recommended for production use, you'd better run `celery-beat` as a different process.

So it's best practice to run it in the server like :

```
celery beat -A messaging_router --loglevel=INFO
```

And if you're using `supervisor` to keep your processes running, you'd add something like the following to your configuration file.

```
[program:api_beat]
command=/path/to/v_envs/v_env/bin/celery -A project beat --loglevel=info
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=your_user (echo $USER)
directory=/path/to/project/root
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/beat.log
redirect_stderr=true
environment=EVN_VAR1="whatever",
```

The reason for this is as the docs say

> You can also start embed beat inside the worker by enabling workers -B option, this is convenient if you will never run more than one worker node, but it’s not commonly used and for that reason is not recommended for production use:

Consider you having more than 1 worker, in maintenance, you need to always be vary of which one of the celery workers you've run with the `-B` and that definitely can be burden.